# Multiple equal to in Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am developing a blood bank app, in order for this to work, when a user requests blood of a particular type, people with compatible blood types should be displayed.
For example : if the requester has a blood group of AB-, then people with blood type : O-, A-,B-,AB- should be shown in Firebase Recycler View. However, I read you can't have multiple equalTo()'s in one query.

```
Query query = findDonorsRef.orderByChild("bloodGroup");
case "AB-":
            option = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<FindDonors>()
                    .setQuery(query.equalTo("O-").equalTo("A-").equalTo("B-").equalTo("AB-"), FindDonors.class)
                    .build();
            break;
```

This is causing the app to crash, can anyone suggest anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I'd do is to have a `campatibleWith` property per user on my DB. So, instead of comparing each compatible blood group to find a match, just compary if user has compatibility with needed blood group.

Make your query more dynamic by passing to it what blood group you're needing.

```
String neededBloodGroup = "AB-";
Query query = findDonorsRef.orderByChild("compatibleWith/".concat(neededBloodGroup)).equalTo(true);
```

Then, instead of checking manually each compatibility, just query to the DB since all the filtering is being already done above.

```
option = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<FindDonors>()
    .setQuery(query, FindDonors.class)
    .build();
```

---

This finds results for donor like:

```
{
    "-KdWh_9KVF16efcSdrji": {
        // Example data
        "name": "Daniel Guzmán",
        "age": 24,
        "gender": "male",
        // Here's the trick
        "bloodGroup": "A-",
        "compatibleWith":{
            "AB-": true
            // All the compatible groups here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer Daniel!

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to alter the sign up code, regardless, this worked very well! I hope one day I will be able to have critical thinking like yours.